# Rails 4 api default limit params do not pass cops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop, ruby-style-guide

This seems a bit crazy here.  Is there another way to write this function to get the cops to pass on it, or should I just make it exempt?

**Code**

```
  def set_default_limit
    params[:limit]  = params[:limit].to_i > 0 ? params[:limit] : AppSettings.api[:default_limit]
    params[:limit]  = AppSettings.api[:max_limit] if params[:limit].to_i > AppSettings.api[:max_limit]
  end
```

**Cop Error**

```
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:66:3: C: Assignment Branch Condition size for set_default_limit is too high. [18.22/15]
  def set_default_limit
  ^^^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do with this method is:

1. if `params[:limit]` exceeds max limit, set it to max limit
2. if `params[:limit]` is less or equal to 0, set it to default limit

Code:

```
def set_default_limit
  api_settings = AppSettings.api

  if params[:limit].to_i > api_settings[:max_limit]
    params[:limit] = api_settings[:max_limit]
  elsif params[:limit].to_i <= 0
    params[:limit] = api_settings[:default_limit]
  end
end
```

Rubocop result:

```
$ cat test.rb
def set_default_limit
  api_settings = AppSettings.api

  if params[:limit].to_i > api_settings[:max_limit]
    params[:limit] = api_settings[:max_limit]
  elsif params[:limit].to_i <= 0
    params[:limit] = api_settings[:default_limit]
  end
end

$ rubocop test.rb
Inspecting 1 file
.

1 file inspected, no offenses detected
```

Comment: thank you.  from the looks of your code and what I tried this " api_settings = AppSettings.api" was the culprit.

Comment: Yes, that's an api call, a major factor of "ABC" size.